# UnicodeDecode error

Tags: python, sql

When querying on string data in a SQL database using pyodbc (specifically pypyodbc), I received this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 56: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by passing `unicode_results=True` into pypyodbc.connect. Reference documentation here: https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module